# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript

I have this function that reads coordination from a XML file, the function works fine when its loose in the window. but when I put it inside a function, then I get the error. `Cannot read property 'style' of null.` on row 127.

The row 127 is

```
document.getElementById(id).style.top=Ynod;
```

Any ideas ?

```
var main = (function () {

    var id=Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);


    document.getElementById("add-new-sticker-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
        id += 1;
        console.log(id);
        add_sticker(""); /**"" removes undefined "*/

        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","/project2/php/insert.php",true); /*Search way... JS to javaScript*/
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("textBoxID="+id);
    });


    function run() {
        readXml();
    }

    function readXml() {
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("get", 'xml/stickers.xml', false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        var myXML = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        stickers = myXML.getElementsByTagName("sticker");

        for (i = 0; i < stickers.length; i++) {
            var idNod = (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); /*Get the ID*/
            var id = idNod;
            var textNod = (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); /* Text*/
            add_sticker(textNod); /*Call creator function*/

            var Xnod = (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("x")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 'px'; /*Get the x position Add PX for pixel*/
            var Ynod = (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("y")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + 'px'; /*Get the y position*/
            var Znod = (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("z")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); /*Get the y position*/
            console.log(Ynod) // Gives correct Y and X
            console.log(Xnod)

            document.getElementById(id).style.top = Ynod;
            document.getElementById(id).style.left = Xnod;
            document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = Znod;
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", run);
    return {};
}());
```

Comment: It means that `document.getElementById(id)` can't find element with specified `id`.

Comment: @VisioN exactly but i have the Id element where it should be ? or Im I calling it wrong ?

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Set breakpoints, step through the code step and step and make sure each variable has the value you expect it to have. The error message is clear, but since we cannot run the code, or know the data, there is not much else we can say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idNod is undefined, make sure there are elements in stickers and try printing stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes to the console.

Comment: How do you know it is `undefined`? It could be anything really.

Comment: @JimCresswell  well Its not undefined since i get the corred ID value when om console.logging it.

Comment: You make a good point, apologies for not reading carefully enough. If the id is correct then I guess the element is not in the DOM at that point, as @FelixKling says, debugging is the way forward. Sorry for not being more useful.

Comment: @JimCresswell np. Explanation is not my strong side anyway :) I will try to debug the code, but somehow everything looks good :(

Answer (score 0):

Okej I found the problem my self.
I was calling a global variable var `id = idNod;`
If I changed the `var id = idNod;` to only `id=idNod`
everything worked :)